# Can't Get Response.email from facebook API v2.5 even email is green in App Reviews

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-app-requests

Can't Get Response.email from facebook API v2.5 even email is green in App Reviews. I used this basic FB.api(), even with SCOPE it doesn't return EMAIL

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mybad,  nothing is wrong with the code, I just did a reset with the permissions on the app.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to ask for additional fields (other than id and name) is this one:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Of course, make sure you have added the `email` permission in the scope:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {

    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Additional [information](http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/).

Btw, you can test API calls [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail&version=v2.6).

Comment: i still cant get the email of the logged in user. do i have to make a request to facebook for the permission? but the email is already approved im my app

Comment: approved does not mean that the user authorized it. see FB.login. and the email address has to be approved in the user account too.

Comment: i used the code you have given and now it only returns me the user ID,

Comment: then you did not authorize correctly, or your email is not approved. try fields: 'email, name' if you need the name too. and read about declarative fields in the changelog.

Comment: mybad,  nothing is wrong with the code, I just did a reset with the permissions on the app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that `FB.login()` is called with `scope: email` so that the token will have the permission to access the user's email.

Then, you should mention the field `email` explicitly while calling `/me` since by default it will return `id` and `name` only.

```
  FB.api('/me?fields=email', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: mybad,  nothing is wrong with the code, I just did a reset with the permissions on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define "email" scope while login, then you could get it when you ask graph.facebook.com:

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';
$params = array(
    'client_id' => $this->strategy['app_id'],
    'redirect_uri' => $this->strategy['redirect_uri'],
    'scope' => 'email',
);
```